# Max subset of arrays whose mean is larger than threshold

Tags: algorithm, set, dynamic-programming, greedy

I recently came across the following problem, and so far got no insight on how to solve it.

> Let S = {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub>} be a set of n arrays defined on the ℝ<sup>6</sup>. That is, each array has 6 entries.
>
> For a given set of arrays, let the mean of a dimension be the average between the coordinates corresponding to that dimension for all elements in the set.
>
> Also, let us define a certain property *P* of a set of arrays as the lowest value amongst all means of a set (there is a total of 6 means, one for each dimension). For instance, if a certain set has {10, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3} as means for its dimensions, then *P* for this set is 1.
>
> Now to the definition of the problem: Return the maximum cardinality amongst all the subsets S' of S such that *P(S') ≥ T*, *T* a known threshold value, or 0 if such subset does not exist. Additionally, output any maximal S' (such that *P(S') ≥ T*).
>
> Summarising: Inputs: the set S and the threshold value T. Output: A certain subset S' (|S'| is evidently immediate).

I first began trying to come up with a greedy solution, but got no success. Then, I moved on to a dynamic programming approach, but could not establish a recursion that solved the problem. I could expand a little more on my thoughts on the solution, but I don't think they would be of much use, given how far I got (or didn't get).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not homework. Maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Seems amenable to a dynamic programming solution. Each subproblem would be the maximum P of a set of a given cardinality which is a subset of a given prefix of S.

Comment: @MarcB A question being homework doesn't make it off topic, and it being a homework question doesn't make it on topic on [math.se], and this seems likely to be an algorithm question, which is more on topic here than on [math.se]. Strange comment for a 100k+ user.

Comment: What is the bound on N, the number of entries?

Comment: @MarcB, from where exactly did you infer this was a homework exercise? For the record, it isn't.

Comment: @Sneftel, I believe my attempts of a dp solution weren't much dissimilar to what you proposed. I'll think a bit harder on what you said, and get back to you if I achieve anything.

Comment: @user1990169, yes. The set S will be given (in the sense that each of its component arrays will be a part of the input), as well as the threshold value T. I forgot to mention what n means in the OP. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: There's no language specified, there's no code, therefore it's not programming. it's math/theory.

Comment: @Gabriel Actually, I no longer believe in that solution. Each cell would actually have to store all Pareto-optimal subsets, and I can't convince myself that that would be polynomially bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Bruteforce evaluation through recursion would have a time complexity of O(2^n) because each array can either be present in the subset or not.

One (still inefficient but slightly better) way to solve this problem is by taking the help of Integer Linear Programming.

```
Define Xi = { 1 if array Vi is present in the maximal subset, 0 otherwise }
Hence Cardinality k = summation(Xi) {i = 1 to n }
```

Also, since the average of all dimensions >= T, this means:

```
d11X1 + d12X2 + ... + d1nXn >= T*k
d21X1 + d22X2 + ... + d2nXn >= T*k
d31X1 + d32X2 + ... + d3nXn >= T*k
d41X1 + d42X2 + ... + d4nXn >= T*k
d51X1 + d52X2 + ... + d5nXn >= T*k
d61X1 + d62X2 + ... + d6nXn >= T*k

Objective function: Maximize( k )
```

Actually you should eliminate k by the cardinality equation but I have included it here for clarity.

Comment: I'm gonna go through you answer in a bit, but regarding the greedy one you posted a few minutes ago, you realise why it doesn't answer the problem correctly, right?